# oauth 1.0a api, use without logging in

Tags: api, rest, oauth, tumblr

I want to use Tumblr's api to pull down some images from blogs.

I was looking through their api and it is oauth 1.0a  , I don't want my user to have to log in, nor do I expected them to have a tumblr account, I just want to dynamically display content from a blog

is this possible with oauth? I'm not sure I have a complete fundamental understanding of that protocol to answer this question mentally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supporting Oauth does not necessarily mean the end user has to provide credentials.  In fact, while Tumblr does use OAuth, they don't actually require it for their api calls that just pull published data, including the one I believe you are interested in.  You will need to register your application here: http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps to get an api key, but then you should be able to access the blog information you are looking for.  I put together a sample scenario on theRightAPI here:  http://therightapi.com/tDWRFGE that shows how this API can be called with the appropriate data.  You can specify a different blog name with a tag of your liking and your api key (I inserted one from their samples) and you can verify whether you get back the result you are expecting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh wow you're right! I don't see how I glazed over that information in the tumblr docs!